# Applying Natural log to an equation

Tags: logarithms

(Note: I'm preparing for an Professional Engineering exam on topics I have not used in over 30 years. So questions might be overly basic. My apologies.)

1) If I take the natural log of one side of an equation, do I have to do so with the other side as well, to not change the equality?

2) If I take the natural log of one element of a multi-element equation, must I take it for all elements so as not to change the equality.

Example 1:  For Equation: $\delta S = mC_p(T_2 - T_1)$, can I take the natural log of the right side only without changing the equality to get this equation?: $\delta S = (S_2 - S_1) = mC_pln(T_2/T_1)$.

Example 2: For Equation: $\delta S = mC_p(T_2 - T_1) - (P_2 - P_1)$, can I take the natural log of the far right element only without changing the equality to get this equation?: $\delta S = (S_2 - S_1) = mC_p(T_2 - T_1) - ln(P_2/P_1)$.

Edit 1: Another way of asking this question... In the equation "y = x*x - a + b" we can factor it to read "y = x^2 - a + b" where we change only the element immediately after the "=" sign (by squaring "x") without changing the equality.

Comment: Equality is a strong condition. Think of it intuitively that if $A=B$ then $A$ is exactly the same as $B$, so if you change only one side of the equation in all likelihood your equality will cease to hold. Thus if you want to keep an equality I recommend you always apply the same function to both sides.

Answer (score 1):

I like to think of logarithms as exponents or taking the square root of equations. So for your parts if:

$$
a=b \implies \ln(a)=\ln(b)
$$
also if

$$
a+b=c+d \implies \ln(a+b)=\ln(c+d)
$$

there are also some other cool properties that might be useful for you

$$
\ln(a^b)=b\ln(a)
$$
$$
\ln\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)=\ln(a)-\ln(b)
$$
$$
\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)
$$
$$
e^{\ln(a)}=a \implies b^{\log_b(a)}=a
$$

These properties also hold true for any base of logarithm